# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blogango_blog" does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a blog using django-blogango given at **"https://github.com/agiliq/django-blogango"** using the following code

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'blogango', 
    'pingback', 
    'taggit',
    'django_xmlrpc',
    'google_analytics',
    'south',

)

DATABASES = {
         'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'NAME': 'mydb',
             'USER': 'myuser',
             'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
             'HOST': 'localhost',
             'PORT': '',
         }
    }
```

when i run syncdb command it gives error **"django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blogango_blog" does not exist".**
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you installed south.. And let us know the output of `pip freeze`.?

Answer (score 1):

I think you using django >1.7 or south. You just need make migrate.