# django 1.8 fails to django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I had a working project with django 1.7, and now I moved it to django 1.8.
I can do `syncdb` and run the app with sqlite, but when I switch to postgres, it fails to do **syncdb**:

```
  Creating tables...
    Creating table x
    Creating table y
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

I tried deleting the database and recreating it.
Also, I tried:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
```

which also fails:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_site" LIMIT 1
```

Please help get this fixed.

Comment: And then if you switch back to sqlite for your database backend and start from an empty database, it works again?

Comment: This may have something to do with changes in Django 1.8: try using the '--fake-initial' option when you migrate if the tables already exist; it used to be implicit, but has now been made explicit: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial Did you try deleting the SQLite DB or the PostgreSQL DB?

Comment: Yes. I've tried deleting the database. When I run `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial myapp` it gives me the error: the app does not have migrations (you cannot selectively sync unmigrated apps)

Comment: It seems to be working now. I deleted all the pyc files.

Comment: Deleting the pyc files was not enough for me ... :-/

Comment: I had a similar problem recently though it was when running tests to this solution didn't work. In the end I discovered that I was missing the 'allauth.socialaccount' app from my installed apps. I don't know why it suddenly started happening though.

Answer (score 16):

I didn't like the idea of commenting/uncommenting code, so I tried a different approach: I migrated "manually" some apps, and then run `django-admin.py migrate` for the remaining ones. After deleting all the `*.pyc` files, my sequence of commands was:

```
$ django-admin.py migrate auth
$ django-admin.py migrate contentypes
$ django-admin.py migrate sites
$ django-admin.py migrate MY_CUSTOM_USER_APP
$ django-admin.py migrate
```

where `MY_CUSTOM_USER_APP` is the name of the application containing the model I set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to in my `settings` file.

Hope it can help. Btw, it seems strange that the best way to synchronize your db in Django 1.8 is so complicated. I wonder if I'm missing something (I'm not very familiar with Django 1.8, I used to work with older versions)

Comment: Switching off apps one by one helped me to find what was the problem

Answer (score 12):

Working on Django 1.10 I found out another solution: 
My application is named "web", and first I call:

```
python manage.py makemigrations web
```

then I call:

```
python manage.py makemigrations auth
```

then I call:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Amazed: IT'S WORKING! :)
It seems auth was searching for the AUTH_USER_MODEL "web.UserProfile" and a relation named web_user_profile, and it didn't find it, hence the error. 
On the other hand, calling makemigrations web first creates the required relation first, before auth is able to check and alert it's not there.

Answer (score 8):

Always migrate db with `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` in newer versions. For the error above if first time your are migrating your database then use `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`. See docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and I spent hours banging my head trying to find a solution, which was hidden in the comments. My problem was that CircleCI couldn't run tests because of this error. And I thought I would need to start fresh with a new and empty DB. But I got the same errors. Everything was seemingly related to 'auth', 'contenttypes' and 'sites'.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609059/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-blogango-blog-does-not-exist), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356963/django-postgres-migration-failing-django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-d), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925726/django-relation-django-site-does-not-exist) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417470/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-app-user-does-not-exist-during-ma). None were solutions for me.

So after having destroyed my DB and created a new one, the only solution I found to entirely avoid these `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError` was to:

1. Comment out all code related to the `User` model.
2. Delete all .pyc files in my project! `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -- {} +` Thanks @max!
3. run `./manage.py migrate` (no fake, no fake-initial, no migration of 'auth' or 'contenttypes' before, juste plain migrate.
4. Uncomment the above code, and run migrate again!

My INSTALLED_APP is the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'mptt',
    'djangobower',
    'honeypot',
    'django_hosts',
    'leaflet',
    'multiselectfield',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'project.<app_name>',
)
```

Comment: The second time you run migrate, the code you commented out will not run, sure, but what happens when you want to deploy your application elsewhere, where the migrations will have to run from scratch? If the user-related code is not necessary, you should just get rid of it.

Comment: Works for me with another model.

Comment: Worked for me too. I didn't have to delete and .pyc files, though. I had to comment out forms.py, urls.py, and views.py.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting migration files, associated .pyc files, and just to be safe all .pyc files with the following commands did not solve my issue.

```
$ find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
$ find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
$ find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -- {} +
```

What ended up solving my issue wasn't clearing caches, it was because I had a function that performed a query as a default function parameter. On init, which is what commands like `makemigrations` and `migrate` do before executing it seems like django (perhaps a python attribute?) initializes all default parameters.

As my database was completely empty (I needed to perform `migrate --run-syncdb` to recreate the tables) when the below default parameter was initialized, it ran a query against the empty database that subsequently failed.

change this:

```
def generate_new_addresses(number=1, index=None, wallet=get_active_wallet()):
   ...
   ...
   return
```

to:

```
def generate_new_addresses(number=1, index=None, wallet=None):
   if not wallet:
      wallet = get_active_wallet()
   ...
   ...
   return
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but my underlying cause was the `__init__.py` file in one of the migrations folders had been deleted from source code but not locally (causing 'Not on my machine' errors).

Migrations folders still need `__init__.py` files, even with Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was appearing when the postgresql driver was able to connect to the database, but the provided user does not have access to the schema or the tables, etc. Instead of saying permission denied, the error being shown is saying that the database table being queried is not being found. Typically in such a situation, the migrate command will also fail with a similar error when it tries to create the `django_migrations` table.

Check for access being granted on the user you're using in database connection in Django.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issues with a `forms.ChoiceForm` queryset. I was able to switch to using [`forms.ModelChoiceForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) which are lazily evaluated and this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case
I made migrations using some other similar looking migration file(1).
Then I deleted it, and made 2 new migration files for replacement(2&3).
And then I was getting this error.

In my case the table was renamed using migration file 1
But django was searching for old table name in migration file 3

So I renamed table manually to old name, and applied migration and It was successful

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, I'd already created the table but it was still showing that the table does not exist.

A simple solution to this is, Just to delete the database of your PostgreSQL and all migration files in your Django project. After deleting run

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Error is basically because db (postgres or sqlite) have not found the relation, for which you are inserting or else performing CRUD.
The solution is to make migrations

`python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> 
 python manage.py migrate`