# "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_user" does not exist" during manage.py test

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

My setup:

- Django 1.8.3
- Python 2.7.10
- Ubuntu 14.04
- django-two-factor-auth==1.2.0

I get the following error when I run `python manage.py test`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/src/venv/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=not keepdb,
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/src/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_user" does not exist
```

When I drop a `print(sql)` statement on line 62 in `django/db/backends/utils.py`, I get following output:

```
CREATE DATABASE "test_dev"

            SELECT c.relname, c.relkind
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "app" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "applied" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL)

            SELECT c.relname, c.relkind
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v')
                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x1"
CREATE TABLE "distributedlock_lock" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "key" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "value" varchar(255) NOT NULL, "timestamp" timestamp with time zone NULL)
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x1"
SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x2"
CREATE TABLE "djkombu_queue" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE)
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x2"
SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x3"
CREATE TABLE "djkombu_message" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "visible" boolean NOT NULL, "sent_at" timestamp with time zone NULL, "payload" text NOT NULL, "queue_id" integer NOT NULL)
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x3"
SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x4"
CREATE TABLE "otp_static_staticdevice" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "user_id" integer NOT NULL, "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL, "confirmed" boolean NOT NULL)
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x4"
SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x5"
CREATE TABLE "otp_static_statictoken" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "device_id" integer NOT NULL, "token" varchar(16) NOT NULL)
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x5"
SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x6"
CREATE TABLE "otp_totp_totpdevice" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "user_id" integer NOT NULL, "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL, "confirmed" boolean NOT NULL, "key" varchar(80) NOT NULL, "step" smallint NOT NULL CHECK ("step" >= 0), "t0" bigint NOT NULL, "digits" smallint NOT NULL CHECK ("digits" >= 0), "tolerance" smallint NOT NULL CHECK ("tolerance" >= 0), "drift" smallint NOT NULL, "last_t" bigint NOT NULL)
RELEASE SAVEPOINT "s140275211773760_x6"
CREATE INDEX "djkombu_queue_name_1c24e49fd475ad53_like" ON "djkombu_queue" ("name" varchar_pattern_ops)
ALTER TABLE "djkombu_message" ADD CONSTRAINT "djkombu_message_queue_id_12778caea7843dd_fk_djkombu_queue_id" FOREIGN KEY ("queue_id") REFERENCES "djkombu_queue" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
CREATE INDEX "djkombu_message_46cf0e59" ON "djkombu_message" ("visible")
CREATE INDEX "djkombu_message_df2f2974" ON "djkombu_message" ("sent_at")
CREATE INDEX "djkombu_message_75249aa1" ON "djkombu_message" ("queue_id")
ALTER TABLE "otp_static_staticdevice" ADD CONSTRAINT "otp_static_staticdevice_user_id_39a61f1bd3ec970d_fk_app_user_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "ff_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

So it is clear to me that my tests blow up while the test database is being setup. Specifically, the attempt to create a foreign key constraint between the `otp_static_staticdevice` table and my app's `app_user` table fails.

My immediate question is, why does django create the OTP table before my app's table? My assumption is that the OTP app is listed first in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. But this is not the case:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'app',
    ...
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'two_factor',
    ...
]
```

Next, I look at `django/core/management/commands/migrate.py`, trying to find out how django determines its order for migrating apps.

Plopping a `pdb.set_trace()` statement on line 264 (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.3/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py#L264)
and looking to see what `app_labels` contains, I get:

```
set(['djangosaml2', 'django_ace', 'recurly', 'staticfiles', 'distributedlock', 'app_overrides', 'messages', 'django_otp', 'kombu_transport_django', 'otp_totp', 'compressor', 'otp_static', 'humanize', 'ajax_select', 'django_extensions', 'import_export', 'raven_compat', 'crispy_forms', 'emoji'])
```

This is as far as I have gotten before I decided to ask for help. Does anyone know how Django might end up *not* creating all the project's apps in the correct order so that decency conflicts do not occur?

Comment: try `./manage.py makemigrations app` first, then continue

Comment: @Paul Did you solve this problem? I'm facing the same thing, except it complains about a different relation.

Answer (score 11):

Got the same issue, and since it happens on `./manage.py test`, your migrations may be broken.
Since Django 1.7, there is a new setting called `MIGRATION_MODULES`, in which you configure your app's migration modules.
Adding the following workaround in settings.py (found [here](https://gist.github.com/NotSqrt/5f3c76cd15e40ef62d09)) skips migrations on tests, and solved it for me:

```
class DisableMigrations(object):

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return "notmigrations"

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Comment: After adding these lines in settings.py file it returns following error- 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notmigrations'

Answer (score 7):

This should be solved by running:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate app
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 4):

```
python manage.py migrate auth
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

You have not given any code so its difficult to understand your models relations. But can I guess that you have passed the ForeignKey model as an instance? Try to give it as a string

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fk_field = models.ForeignKey('path.to.other.model')    # same as from path.models import model
```

This usually works out. Hope it does for you too!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with `manage.py test` when I ran it in gitlab CI jobs, I was able to fix this by creating a variable called `CI` in my `base.py` settings file

`base.py`

```py
"""
Set CI Variable to True when running: "manage.py test"
"""
CI = True
```

and in my `settings.py`:

```py
if CI:
    class DisableMigrations(object):

        def __contains__(self, item):
            return True

        def __getitem__(self, item):
            return None # For Django 1.10+

MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all your app directories have `migrations/` folder and `__init__.py` file in it. If not, make a `migrations/` folder and create `__init__.py` file inside. If you using git, add `!migrations/__init__.py` to the `.gitignore` file

Comment: Tried everything else. This is what worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error beacuse one of my django applications have not `migrations` directory. Try to watch carefully all your apps folders which are present in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, migrations didn't run because I used [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) instead of [`django.test.TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase).

Solution: replace

```py
from unittest import TestCase
```

with

```py
from django.test import TestCase
```