# Testing with Django: stuck at test database creation

Tags: python, django, migration, django-1.8

I was having some trouble running tests for my app and I managed to solved them in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726380/django-1-8-test-issue-programmingerror-relation-auth-user-does-not-exist).

Now executing `python manage.py test` does go through without raising any errors, but it gets stuck at database creation:

When the test database doesn't exist it does create as I can see in pgAdmin, but it gets stuck in the process with this message:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
```

It is stuck here forever, so when I finish the process manually and run `test` again, it says the database exists and prompts me to either delete it and create anew, or cancel the process. I type 'yes' and the process is stuck again with this other message:

```
Destroying old test database 'default'...
```

With pgAdmin open I can't immediately see any new `test_dbname` database, but if I close and open it again I can, there `test_dbname` is, but the `test` task is just stuck there and doesn't go through...

A workaround to this problem is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33389043/3120489), disabling migrations. This way it no longer gets stuck at those messages and the default test is run.

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

However, this just seems to be a bad solution and cheating. There must be a good reason migrations are run when running tests so I don't see a good reason to disable them.

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: @SamBobel I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Did you run it on high verbosity? It is most likely getting stuck on one of your migrations, and that will tell you which one.

Answer (score 23):

Try running `python manage.py test --verbosity=2`. That'll tell you exactly where it's getting stuck, and you can go from there.