# Upgrade to Django 1.8.13. Tests fail but app works. Postgresql tables duplicated

Tags: python, django, postgresql

after a long time procrastinating I decided to upgrade my django app from 1.7.11 to 1.8.13 (due to its LTS). Everything went fine and after fixing some clear errors (I needed to upgrade to `django-mptt==0.8.4` and `django-filter==0.13.0` alongside with `Django==1.8.13`) and deleting some conflicting field attributes, I maganed to run my server properly.

Apparently my app works fine (I test the website manually, performing 2-3 actions and I see no clear error).

However, when running the tests (with `./manage.py test -v 3`), I get the following output:

```
[...]
Running pre-migrate handlers for application debug_toolbar
  Creating tables...
    Creating table corsheaders_corsmodel
    Creating table actstream_follow
    Creating table actstream_action
    Creating table thumbnail_kvstore
    Creating table django_comments
    Creating table django_comment_flags
    Creating table tagging_tag
    Creating table tagging_taggeditem
    Creating table blog_newslettersubscription
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "app_user" does not exist.
```

The app `app` is where I have my `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, i.e in my `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

and in my `app/models.py`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    [...]
```

I have read a lot of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609059/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-blogango-blog-does-not-exist), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356963/django-postgres-migration-failing-django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-d), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925726/django-relation-django-site-does-not-exist), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417470/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-app-user-does-not-exist-during-ma) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897442/django-1-8-fails-to-django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-auth-user-does/35071026#35071026). and I have searched a lot, but I can't find an solution to my problem (none of them worked).

The weird thing is that if I check the database (Postgresql), the table exists. Executing:

```
SELECT relname, reltuples, relpages * 8 / 1024 AS "MB" FROM pg_class ORDER BY relpages DESC;
```

returns:

```
                             relname                    |  reltuples  |  MB   
...                                                     |             |
app_user                                                |        4034 |     0
...                                                     |             |
```

Any clues? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Update:
My `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'crispy_forms',
    'rosetta',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_slack',
    'filebrowser',
    'mptt',
    'corsheaders',
    'actstream',
    'compressor',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'geoposition',
    'reversion',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_auth',
    'django_comments',
    'tagging',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'import_export',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'places',
    'tasks',
    'transmeta',
    'app',
)
```

Comment: post your INSTALLED_APPS please

Comment: Now added. Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to run the tests, but by taking out some of the apps. Exactly the following: `actstream`, `django_comments`, `tagging`, `allauth`, `allauth.account`, `allauth.socialaccount`, `allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook`. If I keep any of them I have the problem shown in the question, but with them tests run and only three don't pass (not related to these apps). So I got a solution but I'm not sure of the implications of this (since I got this project from other people and I don't know exactly what are these apps used for (even if they are used).

Comment: Any way (apart from searching through the project) to know whether these apps are actually used and if there is some consequence by deleting them?

Comment: There is no reason for you to test any of those apps listed. They are third party apps. Well you can test them if you want to but that's a job for the authors of those apps.

Comment: I understand that. It's just that as part of my `INSTALLED_APPS`, they are loaded when tests run. I don't test them myself, just got stuck by running my own apps' tests

Comment: Hang on a second, I think I just spotted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take another look at your error, particularly this bit:

```
   Creating table blog_newslettersubscription
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace/project/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "app_user" does not exist.
```

This says, your `blog` app refers to table in your `app` thus `app` should precede `blog` in your settings.py

Modify your INSTALLED_APPS as follows

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'grappelli',
   ...
   'transmeta',
   'app','blog')
```

Comment: I did this (updated the answer with the INSTALLED_APPS) but no success

Comment: The table exists in both databases (I actually restored a dump locally before trying to upgrade). And all migrations are created. Only one has been created since the update of Django, related to ManyToManyFields' `null=True` that have been deleted and one in the `user` model:
        `migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='groups',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(...)
        )` I guess done by Django itself

Comment: The thing is, even though the table exists both in production and local environments, the problem happens when I run the test command (which creates a new database prefixed with `test_`) so I am a bit lost now

Comment: Sorry for that. I was confusing `test` with `development` environment. I was refering to `development`. The table was not being created in the `test` environment and hence the command didn't run. Thanks!

Comment: I find 61 migration files. 60 of which were running properly with Django 1.7. One was created when updating Django (deleting `null=True` from ManyToManyField(s) and correcting some other warnings that runserver gave me). So my `development` test is fine (as I said `runserver` works well), so I guess the order of the migrations may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, and it works. But if I readd the `allauth` app I still get the same error with another table:  `Creating table blog_newslettersubscription` passes, but if fails when `Creating table allauth_socialtoken` , and now I notice I need the `allauth` app

Comment: yes, you would need it, the order the apps are added to INSTALLED_APPS is important.

Comment: allauth, allauth.account and allauth.socialaccount have to be after django.contrib.sites all these should be before app and blog

Comment: Sorry, an incidence occured and I've been (an I am) focused in solving it. As soon as I can try it I'll let you know, but I have a good feeling :). Thanks!

Comment: I finally managed to run the tests with the allauth application included. Your hints and updating to `django-allauth==0.25.2` did the trick. Now I can move forward (just three tests to fix) and I'll be done. Thank you really much for your support!

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

It seems like 'app' is missing from your INSTALLED_APPS, so the table doesn't get created when the test database is initialized.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my custom apps. My fault. Now updated. Thanks anyway